# Performing a left click at a pre-defined coordinate, in java

Tags: java, mouse, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I would like to perform a left click at a pre-defined coordinate with java. Is there a library for this task ?

Please notice that I do not want to implement a listener to see who performs a mouse click where in my application or anything of that sort, I simply would like to perform a mouse click.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for an external library, when [`java.awt.Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the click should be simulated on a component of your own application, you could use `Component.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)` to deliver the event. alternatively you could determine which component is at the given location and deliver the event directly:

```
Component c = mainComponent.getComponentAt(p);
MouseEvent e = new MouseEvent(c,MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, System.currentTimeMillis(), p.x, p.y, 1, false);
for (MouseListener l : c.getMouseListeners()) {
  l.mouseClicked(e);
}
```